# Generate page with javascript inside and save to local ASP.NET MVC 5 C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

thanks to this controller I can generate this page, inside the page there is a javascript that connects to a remote server not owned by me.

```
public ActionResult Detail(Guid ID) {
        ProdottoManager pm = new ProdottoManager();
        Guid userID = new Guid(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        return View(pm.getDetail(userID, ID));
    }
```

I need once generated this page to download it the whole page html in local, including the results of the javascript execution.
In such a way that at the next opening I can display my page without external dependencies, and therefore even if the remote server to which I connect is offline.
Thanks

Comment: "Thanks"    What have you tried? We are not a code-writing service.

Comment: I have not tried anything because I have not found any solution online

Comment: Make a winforms project, add the ancient webbrowser control, point it at the url, wait and arbitrary amount of time, crawl the webbrowser's .Document or .DocumentText. Or use a tool like get-left which will swap out the remote files with local ones.